# Creating MAVEN PAR module for EAR

Tags: maven, ear, par

In my migration from ANT to MAVEN I arived at a point where I need to create a PAR (persistence Archive) and incorporate it in my final EAR. The MAVEN's documentation

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html#parModule

mentions something about parModule but I didn't find any PAR plugin.

Has anybody a good hint how to create such a PAR archive?

Thank you,
SK

Answer (score 0):

You should attach plain `jar` module as `par` to Ear Plugin - try it.

There is also something like [jboss-packaging-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-packaging-maven-plugin/par-mojo.html) with [par](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-packaging-maven-plugin/par-mojo.html) support. This plugins allow creating `par` module - *builds a deployable JBoss Process Archive*.

### Sample `par` project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jboss-par</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-packaging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi @MariuszS, is this plugin really what I need? On its [page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-packaging-maven-plugin/par-mojo.html) they say that it **Builds a deployable JBoss Process Archive** and what I need is to produce a persistence archive, containing a **persistence.xml**. Or I misunderstood the meaning of the EAR's plugin parModule module? SK

Comment: plain jar can be used for `persisentce.xml`